# Excel: Conditional formatting for column merge

Tags: microsoft-excel, formatting, conditional-formatting, concatenation

I'm looking to create a timetable that is formed by combining material from several worksheets. It does not seem to be possible to automatically consolidate text from several worksheets, but it is, of course, possible to manually place all the material into a single spreadsheet and use the concatenate function.

e.g.

```
=CONCATENATE(B4," ",I4," ",O4)
```

Unfortunately, excel does not allow rich text formatting to be specified in the formula parameters, meaning the merged columns are very difficult to read.

For instance:

```
  0900  Option1 Option2 Option3
        Bulding5 Building8 Building11
        General Appointment Select Appointment General Appointment
  1000  Option4 
        Bulding2 
        Select Appointment
  1100  Option5 Option6 
        Bulding5 Building3 
        General Appointment General Appointment
```

While I can put additional spaces between the concatenated strings, this doesn't do a huge amount to improve matters.

There is no obvious rule to apply whereby conditional formatting could be used to easily distinguish betwen the different values.

Does anyone know how I might apply formatting to distinguish the merged values?

Comment: Why are you concatenating values into one cell in the first place?

Comment: @Excellll As there are numerous cells in the merged columns which are blank; creating additional columns for that data seems, as such, a non-ideal solution.

Comment: Automatically applying different formatting styles within a single cell cannot be done with Excel's conditional formatting feature. You will need to implement a VBA solution to achieve this.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned, in-cell formatting cannot be applied in a formula, or via a formula. You COULD edit your results, especially with VBA instead of by hand to achieve it, but...

You seem willing to have the extra spaces that you mentioned did not overly aid readablity. So presumably your only objection to the multip column idea is the huge number of blank cells it would give, presumably because THAT wouldn't be too readable either.

However, you can create the concatenated strings you are creating now, using some unusual character rather than a space, if it i sat all possible that a value being concatenated brings a space of its own. THEN you can break those strings apart again into individual cells via either the straighforward and easy Data | Text to Columns feature, or any of several formulaic methods you can search for herein to do the breaking apart.

So then you'd have everything in individual cells, with no blank cells in any row's material. You could apply colorful formatting to each column to help them stand out.

That seems like it'd quickly and easily solve the issue as you have the formula already (and nowadays you have a better one to use), Text to Columns is simplicity itself, and then formatting by column doesn't seem too burdensome.